# Firebase token invalid on handout, dependency (QuickBlox) has correct token though

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, quickblox

I'm using Firebase 17.3.3 together with QuickBlox (chat/video SDK) for push notifications in my app, but I am experiencing token invalidations after some time (time varies) when the app is in the background. Is it somehow possible that QuickBlox (or my app) invalidates the token when in the background? I get the NotRegistered error indicating that it is now invalid.

If I upgrade the firebase version above 17.5 (or 17.6, not fully sure), the token that gets sent to QuickBlox for chat still works, but the token I receive from onNewToken and instanceIdResult.getToken() is invalid immediately.

I'm at a complete loss what is happening here.

I use:

```
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"

minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 28

com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3

com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.9.2
com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:3.9.2
com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:3.9.2
com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.9.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickBlox has released an [update](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/releases/tag/3.9.3) to the Android SDK that fixes this issue.

Changes:

- fixed "unsubscribeFromPushes" logic (removed logic for delete token)
- fixed "isSubscribedToPushes" logic (added validation for subscription
  id)

Comment: This fixed the issue, I was calling unsubscribeFromPushes on logout which invalidated the token and didn't properly renew the token (no firebase callback was triggered). This update keeps the tokens valid.